# reading image path from a database

Tags: android

I'm stuck in something that I'm sure rather easy

I have a field in the database that I stored the image name in it, ex 'images/ex1.png'

how can I read this into an imageView?? I tried some code in there but can't get it to work

a good example is highly

Comment: Are you storing this image in a database, or is it being loaded from external storage (internal memory/SD card/HTTP)?

Comment: the images are in the assets/images folder. while in the database I only store their path and name, example 'images/example.png'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the image file directly as the resource for your ImageView (that only takes the resource ID).
Instead you will have to use a [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) to decode it and then use [setImageBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

**EDIT :**

Your problem is that there is no way for you to map the name of the image file with the resource ID in the code. The easier way is probably for you to put together a map table.
First put your image files in the drawable folder (res/drawable/ex1.png...) and then, do something like this in your code :

```
Map map = new HashMap();

// Add key/value pairs to the map
map.put("images/ex1.png", new Integer(R.drawable.ex1));
map.put("images/ex2.png", new Integer(R.drawable.ex2));
// do that for all the images....

String image_name = // query to your database
ImageView the_image_to_change = // findViewById(...)
if (map.containsKey(image_name)) {
    the_image_to_change.setImageResource((Integer)(map.get(image_name)).intValue()); // not sure so much is necessary...
}
```

Comment: I know that that's the jest of it... but no matter what code I use, I cant do it

Comment: Ok, I can see how this works and will try it up later... but isnt there a better way to work this out???  my problem is I have a database of items in an RPG, now imagine each item have an image to show, is this the best way to go about it?

Comment: You probably do not have to use the name of the file itself in your database, but beside that, I don't see any way around it...

Comment: I tried this, but the map.get method returns an object which is not compatible with the setImageResource method that requires an Integer

Comment: You should cast it to an integer

Comment: got it to work, it's going to be a pain to map all the images, but I guess no way around it for now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFilePathString));
```

Your issue is that your file path does not include the root of the device's file system. You have to add this to the beginning of your file path string. This depends on how you save the images. So...

To acquire the appropriate file path to a file on the sd card:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
String filePath = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + imageFilePath;
```

If you're saving your images to internal memory, your app is automatically given a folder to save files to and they will be located there. To find the root to that path use getFilesDir(). For more information on data storage check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.

Comment: this does not work for me for some reason cause decodeResource() needs the string path and ID, which I dont have the id

Comment: Oh my bad, I edited it now it should work. decodeFile() accepts a string that is the filepath of the file. Now it will only work if it is the correct absolute path, otherwise you'll come across an exception.

Comment: the path I have is 'images/example.png' i tried '/images/example.png', yet it does not work

Comment: I updated it again. If you're still struggling with it please give us more information on what you're doing in your app so we can understand how you save the images. There can be issues on where you save the images too.

Comment: well, I'm trying to create an RPG that got many items (naturally), each of which have picture to display. The item list is stored in a database and the path name of the pics is a field in there. The pics are in the assets/images folder

Comment: is there any reason your not using the res/drawable? The only reason I can think of you not using that is saving the images to the sdCard, which wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: I can use the res/drawable, which means the database filed will equal for example "R.drawable.example1"    still I am stuck as to how to get the image from that string... unless the image path should be different?

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing this in your /res/ folder, you need to use a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) in order to get access to this resource.  You shouldn't be accessing resources directly unless you're downloading them externally from the app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: they are not stored in the res folder, they are in the assets/data folder. If that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Use the res/drawable folder. Here's how to load an image from drawable to a Bitmap.

```
Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);
```

More on resources: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html